# C# - UWP -Save username once it is entered into a login screen

Tags: c#, azure, uwp

So I am working on a UWP mobile app for my Capstone Course. As of right now, I have code written to authenticate a user in a table saved in an Azure SQL database. What I need is to save that username entered into something that I can use to either display the username in other parts of the app, or use to search the database and pull only things with that User Name associated.

I have seen some blogs and such regarding a session class, but I cant seem to use that here. Any other help would be appreciated. Please note, I am not using SQL server, I have a connection string in my App.Xaml.cs.

```
public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new 
MobileServiceClient("http://tale-webapp.azurewebsites.net");
```

My Current Login Page is below:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int IsAuth { get; set; }

    //[DataTable("User_Cred")]
    public class User_Cred
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }



    private IMobileServiceSyncTable<User_Cred> todoGetTable = App.MobileService.GetSyncTable<User_Cred>();



    private async Task InitLocalStoreAsync()
    {
        if (!App.MobileService.SyncContext.IsInitialized)
        {
            var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("Tale-DB");
            store.DefineTable<User_Cred>();
            await App.MobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
        }
        await SyncAsync();
    }

    private async Task SyncAsync()
    {
        await App.MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();
        await todoGetTable.PullAsync("User_Cred", todoGetTable.CreateQuery());
    }



    async public void submitAuthBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await InitLocalStoreAsync();

        GetAuthentication();

    }

    async public void GetAuthentication()
    {
        try
        {

            //IMobileServiceTable<User_Cred> todoTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<User_Cred>();

            List<User_Cred> items = await todoGetTable
                .Where(User_Cred => User_Cred.userName == UserNameEnter.Text) 
                .ToListAsync();

            IsAuth = items.Count();



            // Return a List UI control value back to the form

            foreach (var value in items)
            {
                var dialog = new MessageDialog("Welcome Back  " + value.userName);
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(UserHome));
            }


            if (IsAuth > 0)
            {
                var dialog = new MessageDialog("You are Authenticated");
                await dialog.ShowAsync();


            }
            else
            {
                var dialog = new MessageDialog(" Account Does Not Exist, please Register to get Started.");
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception em)
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("An Error Occured: " + em.Message);
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }

    async private void submitAuthBtn_Copy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            User_Cred itemReg = new User_Cred
            {
                userName = UserNameEnter.Text,
                Password = PWEnter.Text

            };
            await App.MobileService.GetTable<User_Cred>().InsertAsync(itemReg);
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("Thank you for Registering! Lets begin");
            await dialog.ShowAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception em)
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("An Error Occured: User Nname 
Already exists.");
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }




}
```

}

After trying, I am still not having luck, the code seems to be working to a point.

This is what I have placed in my Mainpage (which is the log in)

```
private void saveSetting(string userLabel, string userNamelabel)
    {
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = 
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        //Saving your setting  
        localSettings.Values[userLabel] = UserNameEnter.Text;
    }
```

When going to my next page, this is the code I have placed.

```
 private string readSetting(string userLabel)
    {
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        //Reading and returning your setting value
        var value = localSettings.Values[userLabel];
        if (value != null)
            return value.ToString();
        else
            return userLabel;

        UserNameLabelBox.Text = readSetting(userLabel);

    }
```

The problem is that the UserNameLabelBox (textbox) about has a green sqiggly line and VS says unreachable code detected. Nothing shows in that box when running the app.

So now that I have applied the answers given, I run into an error. In my second page that loads after the login page, I get a red line error when I added the UserNameLabelBox.Text = readSetting(userNameLabel); the red line occurs at the userNameLabel stating it does not exist in current context.

To recap: In the login page, i have;

```
private void saveSetting(string userLabel, string userNameLabel)
    {
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = 
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        //Saving your setting  
        localSettings.Values[userLabel] = UserNameEnter.Text;
    }
```

In the following page after login is successful I have;

```
public sealed partial class UserHome : Page
{
    public UserHome()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        UserNameLabelBox.Text = readSetting(userLabel);
    }
```

It is here where the error occurs (above)

```
    private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(UserJournalPage));
    }

    private void aboutUs_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(AboutUs));
    }


    private string readSetting(string userLabel )
    {
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = 
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        //Reading and returning your setting value
        var value = localSettings.Values[userLabel];
        if (value != null)
            return value.ToString();
        else
            return userLabel;
```

Answer (score 3):

I am sure you can do this in multiple ways, but one of the easiest would be to store the username in **Application settings (Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings)**.

You can use this for example :

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = 
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
//setting value 
localSettings.Values["userName"] = "Username Value";

//Getting the setting value 
string value = localSettings.Values["userName"].toString();
```

I would also recommend **encrypting** the username before storing it in the application settings.

[More Info from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data)

---

**Edit**

Example Code sample :

```
//Call this from your code with the setting name and the value that you want to store in it 
private void saveSetting(string settingName,string settingValue){
  Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
  //Saving your setting  
  localSettings.Values[settingName] = settingValue;
}

//Retrieve your setting value
private string readSetting(string settingName){
  Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
  //Reading and returning your setting value
  var value=localSettings.Values[settingName];
  if(value!=null)
    return value.toString();
  else
    return "";
}
```

So after the login for a particular user is successful you can save the username by calling the `saveSetting()` method and later in the next page you can retrieve it by calling the `readSetting()` method.

In order to set the value to your TextBlock you need to write something like this:

```
TextBlockName.Text=readSetting("YourSettingName");
```

Hope this helps.

---

**EDIT 2:**
After seeing your code.. I have identified what is going wrong for you..

[image]
There are 2 things that you are doing wrong here :

1. `UserNameLabelBox.Text` is assigned but it never gets updated.. this is because the function returns the value stored in the settings and the control goes back to the calling method.. So `UserNameLabelBox.Text = readSetting(userLabel)` never gets called.

> The return statement terminates execution of the method in which it appears and returns control to the calling method

Please go through this [Return Statement Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return) to know more.

2.You are calling the method itself from within it.. that is [recursion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3dk2cc3(v=vs.100).aspx) and your code will infinitely call the method `readSetting()`

---

**Solution :** 
Simply remove `UserNameLabelBox.Text = readSetting(userLabel);` from readSetting() method and place it in your **class constructor** -(for example MainPage() is the constructor for MainPage.xaml.cs) .. so as soon as a new instance of the class is created your textblock will get the value.

**Example:**

```
 public YourPageThatComesAfterLogin()
 {
   this.InitializeComponent();
   UserNameLabelBox.Text = readSetting(userLabel);
 }
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but this has me totally confused. When I enter this in, there are errors all over the place, not to mention not knowing how to get this into a text block in the Xaml page that comes after the login is successful.

Comment: I think you are misplacing the c# code.. I have made an edit, hopefully this will help you understand this a bit better. Also,once the setting is saved it will be accessible throughout the application.

Comment: The edit did help as I saw no errors, but when I went to call the string to the text block, it showed an error. If I try to put it in the call section, then nothing shows up. Am I supposed to leave the return " " empty or place the setting name in it? Also, if the value i want entered is the value of the user input, do i name it the input? Example, userName = userNameEnter.text do put userName or the userNameEnter.text?

Comment: You need to save it first to the settings then call the read settings to get the value.. So, from your login page call saveSettings("username",textblockName.text) to save your username and then use the retrieval code from the next page as mentioned in the edited section..

Comment: You have been a tremendous help, and I am sorry for continuing to ask. I am still quite new and I am having issues still. I have added an edit. Perhaps I am miss understanding.

Comment: I have identified the mistake that you are doing.. I have edited my answer again with an explanation of what is going wrong for you..Please go through some of the basics of Object Oriented Programming as it will help you in the long run.. (and don't worry we have all been there where we have no idea what is going on :) .. I will try to help as much as I can..)

Comment: Thanks again, I have applied what you have said with only one issue. I have placed this above.

Comment: The error occurs on the UserNameLabelBox.Text = readSetting(userLabel); the (userLabel) has an error saying that it isnt in context.